# How to store a generic Measurement in Swift?

Tags: swift, foundation

I'd like to have a variable which can represent a single [`Measurement`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement) but may have different unit types. For example, it could store a length or a mass. It seems so simple, but I can't figure it out.

Here's what I tried:

```
struct Data {
    var weight: Measurement<UnitMass>
    var length: Measurement<UnitLength>
    var target = "Weight"

    var valueOfTarget: Measurement<Unit> {
        if target == "Weight" {
            return weight
        } else {
            return length
        }
    }
}

var data = Data(weight: Measurement<UnitMass>(value: 10, unit: UnitMass.kilograms),
                length: Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.centimeters),
                target: "Weight")

print(data.valueOfTarget)
```

I also tried using `<Dimension>` as suggested in another answer, but that had a similar error.

This results in a compiler error:

```
error: cannot convert return expression of type 'Measurement<UnitMass>' to return type 'Measurement<Unit>'
```

Am I'm missing something obvious or is this just not possible?

Comment: How are you planning using `Target`? That would help for figuring out what options could work for you.

Comment: What is `Measurement`? And you probably don't need `<Type>` when you `Type` in the arguments.

Comment: @CraigSiemens It's for weight loss, the user can choose a target as either a weight or a waist size

Comment: @TheRock I added a link to the Measurement class into the question

Comment: Make Target generic.

Comment: I meant how do you intend to use it in your code? Do you need to access the measurement elsewhere? Do you need to pass it around? What kind of operations do you need to do to it?

Comment: @CraigSiemens I see, apologies, I was trying to really boil the question down. I've expanded the context a little bit now

Comment: “Am I'm missing something obvious”  Generics are not covariant. You cannot return a `Measurement<UnitMass>` where a `Measurement<Unit>` is expected. And weight and length are of two different types too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create new generic return values. This seems to compile OK for me.

```
struct Data {
    var weight: Measurement<UnitMass>
    var length: Measurement<UnitLength>
    var target = "Weight"

    var valueOfTarget: Measurement<Unit> {
        if target == "Weight" {
            return Measurement<Unit>(value: weight.value, unit: weight.unit)
        } else {
            return Measurement<Unit>(value: length.value, unit: length.unit)
        }
    }
}

var data = Data(weight: Measurement<UnitMass>(value: 10, unit: UnitMass.kilograms),
                length: Measurement<UnitLength>(value: 10, unit: UnitLength.centimeters),
                target: "Weight")

print(data.valueOfTarget)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't make your own struct named `Data`, because Foundation already has a type named `Data` that's pretty widely used.

Second, since (in a comment) you said “It's for weight loss, the user can choose a target as either a weight or a waist size”, it seems like you should probably model this using an `enum` rather than a `struct`:

```
enum WeightLossTarget {
    case weight(Measurement<UnitMass>)
    case waistSize(Measurement<UnitLength>)
}
```

Third, if you really need to use a `struct`, you can fall back to the Objective-C type `NSMeasurement` for non-generic type:

```
struct WeightLossTarget {
    enum TargetType {
        case weight
        case waistSize
    }

    var weight: Measurement<UnitMass>
    var waistSize: Measurement<UnitLength>
    var target: TargetType

    var valueOfTarget: NSMeasurement {
        switch target {
        case .weight: return weight as NSMeasurement
        case .waistSize: return waistSize as NSMeasurement
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Argh, I wish you hadn’t played the NSMeasurement card.

Comment: I can only play the hand Apple dealt me. ;^)